# My one to many relation does not work, It bringing up the error '' Trying to get property 'senders_name' '' when I try to call it up in view

Tags: laravel, relationship

I want to be able to pass the value of my related table to my views, I am making use of a One to Many relation. also I am trying to do the connection without using a foreign key, well I have been informed that using it for mysql database is not efficient and it would probably brings up error or not do anything.
I actually tested it, I mean the foreign key, it did not work.

Post model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
   //Post model
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Staff');
    }
}
```

Staff model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Staff extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'staff';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
    }
}
```

Create `posts` table migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {   //my post table
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->mediumText('fault_explained');
            $table->string('repair_type');
            $table->string('repair_part');
            $table->integer('repair_total');
            $table->mediumtext('justify');
            $table->string('vendor_name');
            $table->string('vendor_number');
            $table->string('status_option');
            $table->integer('status_value');
            $table->string('vehicle_name');
            $table->string('vehicle_number');
            $table->integer('staff_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Create `staff` table migration:

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStaffTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {   //Staff table
        Schema::create('staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');  
            $table->string('senders_name');
            $table->string('senders_number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('staff');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <main class="st_viewport">
        <div class="border bg-warning">
            <div style="margin-left:14px; margin-top:5px;">
                <span class="h2 wrapper " > <em><b>SUBJECT:</b> {{ $posts->title }}</span></em>
            </div>
            <div class="" style="margin-left:14px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                <em><b>Sent on</b> {{ $posts->created_at }}</em> {{ $posts->staff->senders_name}}
            </div>
```

Comment: perhaps the relationship doesn't exist in the database for that record ... also your HTML markup is not structured in a valid way

Comment: Your migration is incorrect, you don't have a foreign key set up between `posts.staff_id` and `staff.id`. You will need to use the same integer types for both sides to do so. What is `$posts`?

Comment: I understand what you mean, I thought so too but apparently  using foreign keys did not initiate the relationship in the database. I still dont understand it fully but I think it has to do with mysql innoDB encoding not supporting foreign key, and my mysql is innoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Post` model you should use -

```
public function staff()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Staff::class);
    }
```

In the `Staff` model you should use -

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

In CreatePostsTable migration you need to add one more line -

```
$table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('staff');
```

Comment: like i said mysql innoDB doesnt support foreign key, and also  the code

Answer (score -1):

You must replace `App\Models\Staff` with `Staff::class` in your code.

```
...
return $this->belongsTo(Staff::class);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback everyone and I am sorry for the late reply, I found the solution not quite long after posting so I it took me a while to check my account again.